# Can RHEL5/CentOS5 be run on Intel Haswell-EP (E5-26XX V3) CPUs?

Tags: centos5, central-processing-unit, rhel5, cpu-architecture

We need to upgrade the hardware on some of our CentOS 5.11 servers. From Redhat's [Intel CPUs and Supported RHEL Versions page](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/intel), I see that the E5-26XX V2  CPUs are supported. However, the E5-26XX V3 ([Haswell-EP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Haswell-EP.22_.2822_nm.29_Efficient_Performance)) CPUs are listed as *Not Supported*.

I would prefer to use the V3 CPUs. Can anyone tell me if *Not Supported* means that CentOS 5.11 flat-out won't work? Or, perhaps might they work, but just not be able to take advantage of newer chipset instructions (like AVX2). We plan to upgrade to CentOS 6 or CentOS 7 soon, but not before the server upgrades.

Has anyone successfully run RHEL5/CentOS5 on E5-26XX V3 CPUs?

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback, folks. My hope is to move to Centos 7 soon. No fear of systemd here. Looking forward to giving it a try. My plan is to order one E5-v26XX V3 system and finding out if CentOS 5 works or not. If it doesn't, I guess I'll be accelerating my CentOS upgrade plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will run, but it won't take advantage of any new CPU features. CPU upgrades are rarely or never an issue; where you will run into problems is with other hardware in the new server, such as storage and network drivers.

[EL5 is in Production 3 phase](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata), meaning no new hardware enablement will be shipped, and Red Hat expects existing servers to be virtualized onto newer hardware running a newer version of the distribution.

You might be better advised to use the new server(s) as a testbed for your CentOS 7 upgrade, or run C7 on them and virtualize C5 under it, or both.

Comment: As the startup process has been seriously changed in RHEL7 / Centos 7....you might try at least upgrading to RHEL6/Centos6.

Comment: @mdpc systemd is not _that_ scary!

Comment: Yes but if you are depending on other applications they might have NOT updated to the new startup scheme.

Comment: @mdpc There's no problem there; a RHEL7 system will happily run the old-style init scripts. It even does the right thing if you try to use the old-style `service` and `chkconfig` commands on _new_ systemd units.

Comment: I understand.....my comment was just to point out possible things that you might not want to deal with going from 5-->7 at that time.